# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome screen lock policy

Tags: gnome

I need to enforce a screen lock policy, but cannot find any way to do so. If, as root, I run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60
```

it sets a file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` to be that. When a new user logs in (LDAP user), they have a 300 sec (5 min) default and not the system value I set. And they can change it all they want which isn't wanted.

I need to be able to set, and more importantly, enforce a policy on a users screen lock settings.

What is the best way to enforce a policy like this?

Comment: PLease take look. I can not test it https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-lockscreen.html.en

Comment: Thank you very much @nobody.

Comment: i has the same problem i can only manual locking , i has a problem to set policy for auto lock i try many steps but it's not working for me , isuggest to try xscreensaver .

Comment: @desertangels On Ubuntu 18, with Gnome desktop, the steps in the above link worked for me to enforce a policy set through dconf. Is there anything non-standard about the desktop install you have?

Comment: @JasonStover yes i switched from gnome-session to xfce4-session , i enabled gnome-screensaver , i configured as it should to be but without no success .

Answer (score 0):

The link given by nobody in the comment answers this. Thanks much!

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-lockscreen.html.en

Set an administrative lock using dconf.